# iPhone: Puzzling difference in cellForRowAtIndexPath behaviour between iOS 6 and 5.1

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios6, ios5.1, cell-formatting

I would like all cells in my UITableView to *always* show delete accessories and disclosure indicators:

*(the reason for this is that I don't have/don't want an edit button)*

[image]

This works in 5.1 with this code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
  //the usual code
      [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
      cell.editingAccessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

      return cell;
}
```

This is not producing the same behavior in iOS 6.0. When I add a row, it appears without a delete accessory. Interestingly, if I then select the cell (which runs didSelectRowAtIndexPath), I can press cancel in my Details View and only THEN does the delete accessory appear in my table cell.

Can anyone explain this discrepancy? I can't find anything about this in Apple's documentation (if you could point me to something, I would be grateful). Maybe I shouldn't be putting the code in this method in the first place? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you putting the table in edit mode in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`? You should do this once in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @rmaddy This resolved it, thank you very much. I guess I stupidly followed a poor tutorial. If you put your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is being caused by calling `setEditing:animated:` on the table view in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. You should only call that once in `viewDidLoad`.